# Arduino data logger opt. LEDs

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to figure out how to use the optional LEDs on the datalogging Arduino shield. I've written a simple if statement which turns the LED on but it won't turn off when I want it to. Can anyone help me understand why?

I'm using a soil moisture sensor and I want the LED to turn off when the moisture is more than 300. The code works using the built in LED but I am trying to understand how the optional LEDs work.

```cpp
int led2 = 1;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // open serial port, set the baud rate as 9600 bps
  pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // Read data and store
  int val;
  val = analogRead(0); //connect sensor to Analog 0
  Serial.println(val); //print the value to serial port
  if(val < 301) {
    // If soil moisture is less than 301 (0-300 is dry)
    digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
  } else  {
    digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
  }
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Does your serial terminal show that the value hits 301 and _stays_ above 300?

Comment: Why is an optional LED connected to pin 1 aka TX pin? Are you sure it's meant to be user controllable and not just a LED indicating serial activity?

Comment: @gre_gor On this Arduino shield, there are two "optional" LEDs that can be wired to any of the available pins.  They are not connected to anything until the user selects a pin.  In this case, the OP chose to use pin 1 (TX)... which is probably the problem here.

Comment: @Mepix yes it does stay above 300, I didn't know that about pin one so thanks for pointing that out! solved my issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data measured by sensors can be inherently noisy.  Just because you have surpassed a value does not mean that all data points will continue to be above that value.  The LED may have turned OFF, but then have been turned ON again by the sensor value dropping below that threshold.

Try incorporating a boolean into your code to see if you hit that value.  The bool should either be global or used within the loop as static.

```cpp
int led2 = 10; //**DO NOT USE PINS 0 or 1!**

void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
   // open serial port, set the baud rate as 9600 bps
   pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);
}

bool hitThreshold = false;

void loop() {
   // Read data and store
   int val;
   val = analogRead(0); //connect sensor to Analog 0
   Serial.println(val); //print the value to serial port
   if(val <= 300 && !hitThreshold) {
      // If soil moisture is less than 301 (0-300 is dry)
      digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
   } else  {
      hitThreshold = true;
      digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
   }
      delay(1000);
}
```

If you want the LED to go back ON again after a certain period of time, you can incorporate a timer into your code.  Then, you can check whether sufficient time has elapsed instead of just a simple threshold boolean.

You can also implement a running average filter to reduce signal noise, as [discussed in this Arduino forum](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=253938.0).  Play around with it and see what works for you.

**EDIT:**
Do *not* use digital pin 0 and 1 as a digital out while using the serial port.  [Pins 0 and 1 correspond to TX/RX](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Serial).  You will run into [problems](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=26871.0)!  Choose another pin to control the optional LEDs.